# jQuery .first() – does not work with IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The following code adds a cell with a radiobutton to each row of a table and checks the first one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').prepend('<td>');
    $('<input name="delete" type="radio"/>')
        .prependTo('tbody td:first-child')
        .first().attr('checked', true);
});
```

It does not check the first radiobutton with IE 11, jquery-2.1.4 but works properly with FireFox, Chrome and MS Edge; function `last()` works for IE in this case as expected. Is it a bug?

Comment: It has to be `prop('checked', true)`.

Comment: Indeed, it works with `prop()`, but then why `attr()` works with `.last().attr('checked', true)`? Either both work or none I think.

Comment: @user2341923: The attribute is a string value, so `.attr('checked', true)` is actually the same as `.attr('checked', 'true')`. Some browsers expect the value to be `'checked'` rather than `'true'` (or rather some browsers are more lenient and accept that it's not the correct `'checked'` value).

Comment: @user2341923: With the attribute, [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) requires that the attribute (as opposed to property) must be *removed/absent* for the flag not to be set, and must be either `""` or the name of the attribute (`"checked"`, in this case) for it to be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are settings the `checked` attribute to `"true"` instead of `"checked"`, which only works for browsers that choose to inpret that as a value that means `"checked"`. Also, as the attribute is the initial value of the input, it doesn't always work after the element is created.

You want to set the current value instead of the initial value, which is the `checked` property instead of the `checked` attribute. Use the `prop` method to set the `checked` property to `true`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').prepend('<td>');
    $('<input name="delete" type="radio"/>')
        .prependTo('tbody td:first-child')
        .first().prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with `first`; it's to do with what you're *doing* with the first one.

When using `true`/`false` with `checked`, you want to use the *property*, not the attribute. jQuery used to jump through a **lot** of hoops to set properties/attributes for people reliably cross-browser when they used `attr` with boolean properties, but many of those hoops were removed (and only some added back) when they added `prop` in v1.6.

If you use `prop`, it works on IE11, too:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').prepend('<td>');
    $('<input name="delete" type="radio"/>')
        .prependTo('tbody td:first-child')
        .first().prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Just for completeness: If you *did* want to use the attribute, [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) requires that the attribute must be *removed/absent* for the flag not to be set, and must be either `""` or the name of the attribute (`"checked"`, in this case) for it to be set:

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> **Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.